# How do I go about asking a question already asked but unanswered?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I recently asked this question [What exactly is an "Ubuntu App", as made with the Ubuntu SDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579262/what-exactly-is-an-ubuntu-app-as-made-with-the-ubuntu-sdk) but to date it has no answers or comments and very few views.

It seems to me to be a reasonable question about something topical (Canonical seem to be pushing the idea of Ubuntu Apps quite strongly) - is it not a good question, or is it a bit niche?

If I copy and paste it into a new question, it might get correctly flagged as being a duplicate, which doesn't really help me, and I don't think repeated questions are good for the site anyway.

What is the correct way for me to go about getting a bit more attention for my question?

Comment: I've started a bounty. Comment here or ping me in the chatroom if you get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @muru Thank you for that.

Comment: Had any luck with the question? The bounty is due to expire soon.

Comment: @muru No. Two answers, but neither answer the question or tell me anything I didn't already know.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest flagging the question if you're unable to start a bounty.

If the new question generates answers, the two could be merged.

The other option is to start a bounty, but this only works if you've got the rep, of course, and should be used carefully because without moderator intervention, you're not getting that rep back.